# mousewheel event not working on Mac machine safari browser

Tags: jquery, safari, mousewheel

I am trying to grab the mousewheel event in iframe on Mac machine with Safari Browser,but the event is not being grabbed.It is working well on Windows (Chrome and Safari) and Mac Chrome browser.Neither it is showing any error on console.

I have tried other events also but could not find the appropriate solution.

I have used the following code

```
$('#divelingOverlay_wrapper').on('mousewheel scroll wheel DOMMouseScroll touchmove MozMousePixelScroll', function (ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: `mousewheel` is not a standard event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel

Comment: You can use mousewheel plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

Comment: Jai,that is why we have also used the other events.But they are also not working

Answer (score 0):

`mousewheel` event does not work well with Mac browsers.  You can try `$(window).scroll` for your own purpose.

Comment: I have added $('#id').on('scroll') also,as you can see in the sample code.

Comment: Yes, I have read that. I had faced the same issue one one of my project and I had no success in using `$("#id").on("scroll")`to get the good result in Mac.  The `.mousewheel()` event was not fired and `scroll` event was fired many times on Safari especially. So it would be good to avoid `mousewheel` for Mac.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the suggestion.So finally what solution worked for you if neither the mousewheel nor the scroll worked.

Comment: I had to add my custom handler to $(window).scroll() event